# How I automatically rotate annotationView image following map rotating in MKMapKit?

Tags: swift, mapkit, swiftui

My code does rotate `annotationViewImage`, when the map rotated.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
      let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "mark")
      annotationView.image =  UIImage(named: "pinArrow")
      let ang = mapView.camera.heading
      let radi = Double.pi * Double(ang / 360)
      let resultAng = 2 * Float(radi)
      annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-resultAng))
      annotationView.canShowCallout = true
              return annotationView
}
```

above code, when the map rotates, do not implement the above method.
So add below code

```
func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
    print("visible")
    let anns = mapView.annotations
    mapView.removeAnnotations(anns)
    mapView.addAnnotations(anns)
}
```

and then, when map rotate, so do `annotationView` image.
But so a few some slow and loading time a few some long.
Because map moving delegate of above code, so many doing and repeat.

I seek a more simple way without loading slow.
How rotate sync map and `annotationView` image?

Comment: App UI is blocked due to heavy operations, Use async block to make it smooth.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, an overlay might me the right thing. Or an overlay + an annotation.